# JQuery to traverse through webgrid rows and change label backcolor

Tags: jquery

I am writing a WebGrid that has labels for each column. For the columns, PREV STAT MISSION, STAT MISSION, PREV STAT QUAL, and STAT QUAL, there are values from 1 to 4. I want to change the backcolor of the label to display the following 1: green 2:yellow, 3:red and 4 : black.

How do I write a JQuery function that will go through every row in the webgrid that will check for the values of PREV STAT MISSION, STAT MISSION, PREV STAT QUAL, and STAT QUAL and change the label backcolor?

Thanks and much appreciated.

```
<div id="gvFacilities">
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");

        <div id="gridContent">
            @grid.GetHtml(
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "gvFacilities" },
            tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("SITE_UID", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"></span><label id="lblSiteUID" class="edit-mode">@item.SITE_UID</label></text>, style: "color:blue"),
                grid.Column("FACNO", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"><label id="lblFacNo" class="edit-mode">@item.FACNO</label></span></text>),
                grid.Column("CATCODE", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"><label id="lblCatCode" class="edit-mode">@item.CATCODE</label></span></text>),
                grid.Column("UIC", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"><label id="lblUIC" class="edit-mode">@item.UIC</label></span></text>),
                grid.Column("PREV_STAT_MISSION", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"><label id="lblPrevStatMission" class="edit-mode"> @(item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 1 ? " F1 " : item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 2 ? "  F2 " : item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 3 ? " F3 " : item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 4 ? " F4 " : item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 5 ? " F5 " : "")</label></span></text>),
                grid.Column("STAT_MISSION", format: @<text><span class="display-mode"><label id="lblStatMission" class="edit-mode">@(item.STAT_MISSION == 1 ? "F1" : item.STAT_MISSION == 2 ? "F2" : item.STAT_MISSION == 3 ? "F3" : item.STAT_MISSION == 4 ? "F4" : item.STAT_MISSION == 5 ? "F5" : "")</label></span></text>),
                grid.Column("PREV_STAT_QUAL", format: @<text><span class="display-mode"><label id="lblPrevStatQual" class="edit-mode">@(item.PREV_STAT_QUAL == 1 ? "Q1" : item.PREV_STAT_QUAL == 2 ? "Q2" : item.PREV_STAT_QUAL == 3 ? "Q3" : item.PREV_STAT_QUAL == 4 ? "Q4" : item.PREV_STAT_QUAL == 5 ? "Q5" : "")</label></span></text>),
                grid.Column("STAT_QUAL", format: @<text><span class="display-mode"><label id="lblStatQual" class="edit-mode">@(item.STAT_QUAL == 1 ? "Q1" : item.PREV_STAT_QUAL == 2 ? "Q2" : item.PREV_STAT_QUAL == 3 ? "Q3" : item.PREV_STAT_QUAL == 4 ? "Q4" : item.PREV_STAT_QUAL == 5 ? "Q5" : "")</label></span> </text>),
                grid.Column("CYRATING", format: @<text><span class="display-mode"><label id="lblCYRating" class="edit-mode">@(item.CYRATING != null ? item.CYRATING : "")</label></span></text>),
                grid.Column("CONSTR_TYPE", format: @<text><span class="display-mode"><label id="lblType" class="edit-mode">@(item.CONSTR_TYPE != null ? item.CONSTR_TYPE : "")</label></span> </text>),    
                grid.Column("ASSET_UID", format: @<text><span class="display-mode"><label id="lblAssetUID" class="edit-mode">@(item.ASSET_UID != null ? item.ASSET_UID : "")</label></span></text>),
                grid.Column("RATINGDUE", format: @<text><span class="display-mode"><label id="lblRatingDue" class="edit-mode">@(item.RATINGDUE != null ? item.RATINGDUE : "")</label></span></text>),
                grid.Column("AMOUNT", format: @<text><span class="display-mode"><label id="lblAmount" class="edit-mode">@(item.AMOUNT != null ? item.AMOUNT : "")</label></span></text>),    
                grid.Column("CATCODE_UM", format: @<text><span class="display-mode"><label id="lblCatcodeUM" class="edit-mode">@(item.CATCODE_UM != null ? item.CATCODE_UM : "")</label></span></text>),
                grid.Column("UIC", format: @<text><span class="display-mode"><label id="lblUIC" class="edit-mode">@(item.UIC != null ? item.UIC : "")</label></span></text>)

               ))
        </div>
    }
</div>
```